# Configuring Windows for external/public access to web service rest API using Node.js

Tags: javascript, android, windows, rest, networking

I'm new to programming and having a really bad time with connecting android app to an Oracle DB through a restAPI web service built with NodeJs.

I still didn't understand how to match all the pieces of the whole functionality logic but following the steps of [this tutorial](https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/) I started to have some hope.

I managed to make the webservice to run from the Windows Server machine which the oracle database is running and query some data but I could only access the http link browsing within the Windows Server terminal, but public access to this machine is available for similar applications already running.

I couldn't set port 80 or 8080 to run the web server, I got the error as follows:

```
C:\NodeServer\Servidor>node index.js
Starting application
Initializing database module
Initializing web server module
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1301:21)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1503:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -4092,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 80
}
```

I made some research on this error message and it seems like there's a port range which needs elevated privileges to be used for public access (I have administrator access to the terminal server), there is another rest application running in this windows server machine with port 212 and the node server does not crash when set with it but when I try to connect to the http link a login/password prompt pops, but again only locally, when I try from my home wifi nothing loads.

I'm suspicious that the IP address and port number to make the Node Webserver access public must be created in the router settings of the database machine, but this particular company doesn't mind much about security since there's no really relevant information running in this oracle database and they made the access external to the windows server, but it gave me another doubt:
If they decided to make the connection local only and set a wireless connection to work both the cellphones with the app and the oracle database there would be no problem to run and access the NodeJS web service in localhost:3000, right?

Comment: Try doing `set PORT=8090` before running the command, you might have other process running on port 80

Comment: unfortunately I got timeout again, the file which set the port is as it goes
"module.exports = {
  port: 8090
};"
so the connections tring calls
"    httpServer.listen(webServerConfig.port,"0.0.0.0")
      .on('listening', () => {"
inside the terminal server connection the http address worked but not in my PC

Comment: Exposing Windows networking for remote HTTP access to a Node.js webservice isn't related to the DB so I updated the question tags.  It sounds like a mix of trying to use a privileged port and/or a firewall configuration issue.